# Is this proof of the convergence in probability version of Fatou's lemma well-known?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Wanting to prove the convergence in probability version of Fatou's lemma from the definitions, so to speak, I came up with the following argument; if it works, then aside from nonnegativity it only requires the assumption that $\lim_{n\to\infty} P(X_n \leq X - \varepsilon) = 0$ for every $\varepsilon > 0$. (Is there a commonly used term for the latter condition?) I've never seen this argument in a textbook, and am curious as to whether it's well-known.

Suppose $\{X,X_1,X_2,\dots\}$ is a collection of nonnegative random variables on  a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ and that $\lim_{n\to\infty} P(X_n \leq X - \varepsilon)=0$ for each $\varepsilon>0$.

For any simple nonnegative random variable $Z$ with $0\leq Z \leq X$ and any $\varepsilon > 0$, define simple random variables $Y_n$ $(n\geq 1)$ by
$$
Y_n:= (Z - \varepsilon)1_{\{X_n > Z - \varepsilon\}}
$$
Set $M:=\max Z(\Omega)$; then $Y_n \leq M$ for every $n\geq 1$, and
\begin{align*}
E(Z) - \varepsilon 
   &= E((Z-\varepsilon)1_{\{X_n > Z - \varepsilon\}}) + E((Z-\varepsilon)1_{\{X_n \leq Z - \varepsilon\}})\\ 
   &= E(Y_n) + E((Z-\varepsilon)1_{\{X_n \leq Z - \varepsilon\}}) \\
   &\leq E(Y_n\vee 0) + E((Z - \varepsilon)1_{\{X_n \leq Z - \varepsilon\}} )\\
   &\leq E(X_n) +  E((Z - \varepsilon)1_{\{X_n \leq Z - \varepsilon\}} ) \\
   &\leq E(X_n) + M P\{X_n \leq X - \varepsilon\} \\
\end{align*}
since $\{X_n \leq Z - \varepsilon\}\subseteq \{X_n \leq X - \varepsilon\}$ and $Y_n\vee 0$ is a simple nonnegative random variable with $Y_n\vee 0 \leq X_n$.

Taking $\liminf$ gives
$$
E(Z) - \varepsilon \leq \liminf_{n\to\infty} E(X_n) + M\limsup_{n\to\infty} P\{X_n < X - \varepsilon\} = \liminf_{n\to\infty}E(X_n)
$$

Since the inequality holds for any $\varepsilon>0$ and simple $Z$ with $0\leq Z \leq X$ it follows that $E(X)\leq \liminf_{n\to\infty} E(X_n)$.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the result follows because, as $X$ is nonnegative, $E(X)$ is the supremum of the values $E(Z)$ where $Z$ is a simple random variable with $0 \leq Z \leq X$.

Comment: In the inequality $\liminf_{n\to\infty}(a_n + b_n) \leq \liminf_{n\to\infty} a_n + \limsup_{n\to\infty} b_n$ I let $a_n:= E(X_n)$ and $b_n:=M P\{X_n \leq X - \varepsilon\}$.